# Get-content not producing an array that Invoke-restmethod can process

Tags: powershell, safe-browsing-api

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050622/how-can-i-query-multiple-urls-with-google-safe-browsing-api-using-powershell), instead of using a long array in the script I wanted to draw from a text file.  So I replaced this:

$URLs = 'http://websiteone.com','http://websitetwo.com','http://websitethree.com'

with this

$URLs = Get-Content ./urlfile.txt

or (functionally the same as far I know) this

$URLs = @(Get-Content ./urlfile.txt)

But I end up with **Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

Incorporating the great response form my last question, my foreach loop looks like this:

```
foreach($URL in $URLs) {
    $BODY = @([pscustomobject]@{"client" = @{"clientId" = "company"; "clientVersion" = "1.0"}; "threatInfo" = @{"threatTypes" = "MALWARE","SOCIAL_ENGINEERING","THREAT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED","UNWANTED_SOFTWARE","POTENTIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION"; "platformTypes" = "ANY_PLATFORM"; "threatEntryTypes" = "URL","EXECUTABLE","THREAT_ENTRY_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"; "threatEntries" = @{"url" = $URL}}})
    $JSONBODY = $BODY | ConvertTo-Json
    $Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'POST' -Uri $Uri -Body $JSONBODY -Headers $HEADERS
    if ( ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Result)) ) {} else {write-host $URL "ALERT: Safe browsing match!"}
}
```

... but this doesn't work if I create the array with the Get-Content cmdlet.  If I run the script either way, then type $URLs, I get the exact same data returned.  What am I doing wrong with get-content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet is there to make one `Rest` request at a time and can't take an array.

You will need to add a `forEach` loop to step through your `$urls` one at a time, something like this:

```
foreach($url in $urls){

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url 
    #do something with $result
}
```

So to integrate into your sample from the previous question, you should have a `urls.txt` file which looks like this:

```
http://google.com
http://small.com
https://fast.com/
```

And then your code would look like this:

```
$URLs = get-content .\urls.txt
$HEADERS = @{ 'Content-Type' = "application/json" }
$GOOGLE_API_KEY='[API Key]'
$Uri = 'https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key='+ $GOOGLE_API_KEY

foreach($URL in $URLs) {
    $BODY = @([pscustomobject]@{"client" = @{"clientId" = "company"; "clientVersion" = "1.0"}; "threatInfo" = @{"threatTypes" = "MALWARE","SOCIAL_ENGINEERING","THREAT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED","UNWANTED_SOFTWARE","POTENTIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION"; "platformTypes" = "ANY_PLATFORM"; "threatEntryTypes" = "URL"; "threatEntries" = @{"url" = $URL}}})
    $JSONBODY = $BODY | ConvertTo-Json
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'POST' -Uri $Uri -Body $JSONBODY -Headers $HEADERS

    [pscustomObject]@{SiteName=$url;ThreatInfo=$result.Matches}
}
```

This would load up the list of `$urls` from your text file, then run a Rest Request on each, storing the result in `$result`.  Finally, it will make a new PowerShell Object with the site name and show you if there are any matches from the [Google SafeBrowsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api#http-post-response).

You'll need to run the command interactively and see which properties from `$result` are meaningful to you, but you can see all of the expected properties in the Google API Docs.

**Edit**

Found the bug.  It turns out when we use `Get-Content` the object returned back retains some of the document formatting information from the original file!  We can see this by inspecting `$JSONBODY`.  We also see that the conversion to `Json` from `[PSCustomObject` is leaving a lot of cruft behind too.

To fix this, we should cast `$URL` into a string using the `ToString()` method and also ditch casting to `[psCustomObject]` too as shown below.

```
$BODY = @{
        "client" = @{
            "clientId" = "company"; "clientVersion" = "1.0"
            }; 
            "threatInfo" = @{
                "threatTypes" = "MALWARE",
                "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING",
                "THREAT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
                "UNWANTED_SOFTWARE",
                "POTENTIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION"; "platformTypes" = "ANY_PLATFORM"; "threatEntryTypes" = "URL"; "threatEntries" = @{
                    "url" = $URL.ToString()
                }
            }
        }
$JSONBODY = $BODY | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been clear that I was using the foreach loop, I edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: Check to see if your urls.txt file looks drastically different than what I just editted in.